# How can I put a linearlayout at a random place of the screen?

Tags: android, layout

My request is quite simple: I just want to display some text at a random place of the screen.

I was expecting, as I used:

```
int x = r.nextInt(width - layout.getWidth());
```

and

```
int y = r.nextInt(height - layout.getHeight());
```

that my layout would perfectly fit the screen.

Unfortunately, my text is sometimes at the right of the screen and appear in multiple lines!

Here is my code

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    layout.addView(clock);
    layout.addView(txtView);

    Random r = new Random();    
    int x = r.nextInt(width - layout.getWidth());
    int y = r.nextInt(height - layout.getHeight());

    layout.setPadding(x, y, 0, 0);
    setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem I had was that

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

returns a value including the top statusBar (or notification, don't know how to call it) and the software buttons at the bottom.

The solution was to create a dummy layout in background and measure it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` as your container instead of `LinearLayout` as this is what is is designed for.

Comment: Same result, the text sometimes appear at the right of the screen and is "cutted"